# How can I expand element automatically in The Web using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a notebook and a monitor using 1920 X 1080 resolution but they have different screen size. (notebook : 13 inch, PC monitor : 19 inch)

I worked on the notebook screen, I defined the element 'Height' at 'Value X'px fixed (example value...). and then when I moved my internet browsers (chrome, IE, etc.) to PC screen, it showed me a lot of empty space as follows.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

someone suggested me using media query... is it ok?

Comment: Has anyone suggested using Google yet?

Comment: try to use media query and use google also

Comment: If you can show some relevant code that might help. Without seeing code, it looks like bootstrap is already doing something in it's media query to adjust the height for you.

Comment: Don't use `%`. It means (of parent) Use [`vw` and `vh`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) (it means of viewport - a.k.a device) and that's what you seem to wanth here. Actually, read them all and use what you want/need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made an example below.. keeping the width and height in percentages that will adjust automatically on any device you will open.

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box}
body,html{ width:100%; height:100%}
.bluebg{ width:100%; height:100%; background:blue; padding:20px;}
.yellowbg{ width:100%; height:100%; background:yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="bluebg">
  <div class="yellowbg">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To make your life easier, if you use the `vh` (viewport height) and `vw` (viewport width) units instead of percentages, you won't have to bother making the body and html 100%.